# Получение части URL с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Суть в чем, делаю расширение для хром, ему нужно обработать адрес открытой страницы. Структура сайта такая: http://site.com/12345  http://site.com/raz/dva/12345 Необходимо вытащить отсюда цифры 12345, но еще одно условие до знака #, т.к. возможна ссылка с якорем. Т.е. условие звучит как "все цифры от знака / до #" Думаю, что надо regexp'ом делать, но с ним вообще не работал.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: `.match(/\/(\d+)/)[1]`

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, это то, что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка на статью по регулярным выражениям: http://javascript.ru/regexp

```js
(function() {
  var href = 'http://site.com/link/12345#якорь'; // Наша псевдоссылка
  
  // Регулярное выражение для это ссылки
  var reg = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\/site\.com[^#?]*\/(\d+)\#?.*$/, '$1');
      
  console.log(reg)
}());
```

Comment: Из `http://site.com/12345#abc/6789` вытащит `6789` https://regex101.com/r/tTXR3c/1

Comment: @Visman, оу, просчитал - исправил :)